# Problems with implementing type_id without RTTI

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to get type_id into my Arduino project. Enabling RTTI is not an option, but I need a way to determine the type of an object at runtime (and nothing more than that).

I've read many articles and StackOverflow posts on this (and i'll admint I do not understand all of it), but whatever example i try to implement, it somehow doesn't do what I want, which is return the type_id of the derived class.

The underlying example (based on code from Axel Menzel) returns the following:

> Hello World
>   a: 1
>   b: 2
>   b2: 1

I don't understand why b2 is returning 1.
Can anybody shed some light on this for me?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static int generateId()
{
  static int typeID; // automatically init with 0
  return ++typeID;
}

template <typename T>
struct MetaTypeInfo
{
  static int getTypeInfo()
  {
    static const int typeID = generateId();
    return typeID;
  };
};

class ClassA {
public:
    virtual ~ClassA() {};
    static MetaTypeInfo<ClassA> typeinfo;
};

class ClassB: public ClassA {
public:
    virtual ~ClassB() {};
    static MetaTypeInfo<ClassB> typeinfo;
};


int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 

   ClassA a;
   ClassB b;
   ClassA* b2 = new ClassB();

   cout << "a: " << a.typeinfo.getTypeInfo() << endl;
   cout << "b: " << b.typeinfo.getTypeInfo() << endl;
   cout << "b2: " << b2->typeinfo.getTypeInfo() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: static data members aren't virtual

Comment: Do you really need to get the actual type?  Normally that is a design flaw and the problem can be solved in a way that doesn't require you to know the type.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know it should be solved with Visitor pattern / Double dispatch but that is way to heavy for the sporadic use and the amount of memory that it would take. Already on the edge of available memory as I'm not a embedded coder by trade and not used to give memory use much thought ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a virtual method that is overridden in every class that needs the Type-identification. For ease of coding I defined the code that should be repeated in every class in a single #define.

Any suggestions for improvement are welcome

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static type_id generateId()
{
  static int typeID; // automatically init with 0
  return ++typeID;
}

template <typename T>
struct MetaTypeInfo
{
  static int getTypeInfo()
  {
    static const int typeID = generateId();
    return typeID;
  };
};

#define TYPEINFO(T)                               \
  static int getClassTypeId() {                   \
        return typeinfo.getTypeInfo();            \
    }                                             \
    virtual int getTypeId() {                     \
        return typeinfo.getTypeInfo();            \
    }                                             \
    static MetaTypeInfo<T> typeinfo


class ClassA {
public:
    virtual ~ClassA() {};
    TYPEINFO(ClassA);
    int i = 0;
};

class ClassB: public ClassA {
public:
    virtual ~ClassB() {};
    TYPEINFO(ClassB);
};

int main()
{
   ClassA a;
   ClassB b;
   ClassA* b2 = new ClassB();

   cout << "A: " << ClassA::getClassTypeId()       << endl;
   cout << "B: " << ClassB::getClassTypeId()       << endl;
   cout << "a: " << a.getTypeId() << endl;
   cout << "b: " << b.getTypeId() << endl;
   cout << "b2: " << (b2)->getTypeId() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
$main
A: 1
B: 2
a: 1
b: 2
b2: 2
```